# Need help to provide cross-screen fluidity of images?

Tags: android, xml

Can anyone please suggest me an edit so that the image and the text could appear in the same ratio across all devices this code only looks on screen size from 3.2 - 4.5 inches screen please help.the drawable hdpi,ldpi and mdpi sizes of image are 161*232,75*108,100*144 how ever i don't have xhdpi and xxhdpi as they make the image even smaller on large screen devices

Here is the code for mainactivty.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/radial_background"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_switch_on" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="15dip"
    android:text="@string/about"
    android:textColor="#292929"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: also please point out where the problem actually is